# i want to give padding in pixels and fix width in percentage

Tags: css

Outer div which hold thumbnails contains padding: 20px 40px 0px 40px. Now I want to fix width in percentage for responsive layout. If width is not specified, then there is empty space on right side.Can someone help me, how to calculate the width in '%' if padding is there in px.

Answer (score 2):

**Try to** `box-sizing`

```
div{
padding: 20px 40px 0px 40px;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

more about **[box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
         <div class="child"></div>
         <div class="child"></div>
         <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.outer{display:block; padding: 20px 40px 0px 40px}
.inner{display:block;}
.child{width:33.33%}
```